# ant xmltask copy files

Tags: xml, ant

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<job>
<files>
        <file src="file:\C:\tmp\myfile.xml" path="myfile.xml" format="dita"/>
        <file src="file:\C:\tmp\myfile2.xml" path="myfile2.xml" format="dita"/>
</files>
</job>
```

I try with the ant script to read the contents of the xml file and then would like to copy the corresponding files. Here is my ant script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="TPreProcess" default="start" basedir="." >
<target name="start">
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>

<xmltask source="${basedir}${file.separator}.job.xml" report="false" >  

    <call path="//job/files/file[@format='dita' or @format='ditamap' ]" target="copy-xml"  buffer="abc">
            <param name="copySourcesFile" path="@src"/>
     </call>

</xmltask>
</target>


<target name="copy-xml" depends="" unless="" description="copy xml files">
<copy file="${copySourcesFile}" todir="C:${file.separator}tmp${file.separator}test_dita${file.separator}" failonerror="false" flatten="true"/>
</target>
</project>
```

The ant script is located in a plugin folder. In the log file of the executed ant file, it is always shown that it can not find the files to be copied. You can see that he always puts the plugin folder before it.

---

copy-xml:

[copy] Warning: Could not find file Q:\DITA\Dita-Open-Toolkit\plugins\com.xxxxx.dita.tran.process\file:\C:\tmp\myfile.txt to copy.

---

What am I doing wrong? How do I get only the actual file path and find the files to copy?

Comment: `copy` task can copy the files. Why xmltask?

Comment: I tried to use xmltask because I have to read the files to be copied from the xml file (including filters to certain attributes). There are file nodes with attribute values that should not be copied. Or can I read the xml file without xmltask? An idea?

Comment: Copy always builds the path according to basedir entry before it. When I change the basedir entry to something other than "." , it no longer takes the plugin folder before. With a test output of copySourcesFile in the target I see that the actual file name to be copied correctly arrives in the target. So something happens in copy itself. But I do not know how to prevent this. Any idea?

Comment: Ant can't handle `file:` protocol references with backslashes. Change your source XML to either `<file src="file:///c:/tmp/myfile.xml" ...>` or simply `<file src="C:\tmp\myfile.xml" ...>`.

Comment: I tried file:\C:\tmp\myfile.xml and also file:///C:/tmp/myfile.xml with no effect. It still put the plugin folder before.


Warning: Could not find file Q:\DITA\Dita-Open-Toolkit\plugins\com.xxxxx.dita.tran.process\file:\C:\tmp\myfile.xml to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I got it running like this:

```
<xmltask source="${basedir}${file.separator}.job.xml" report="false">

<call path="//job/files/file[@format='dita' or @format='ditamap' ]" target="copy-xml"  buffer="abc"> 
<param name="copySourcesFile" path="@src"/> 

</call>


<target name="copy-xml" depends="" unless="" description="copy xml files" >  

 <property name="copySourcesFile" value="${copySourcesFile}" /> 

 <basename property="file.basename" file="${copySourcesFile}"/>
 <dirname property="path.dirname" file="${copySourcesFile}"/>

 <pathconvert property="file.path.stripped">
        <file file="${path.dirname}" />
        <!-- path convert strips off the leading ${basedir} and "\file\:" -->
        <map from="${basedir}\file:\" to="" />
 </pathconvert>  
<copy todir="C:${file.separator}tmp${file.separator}" failonerror="false">
<fileset dir="${file.path.stripped}">
<include name="${file.basename}" />
</fileset>
</copy>
</target>
```

But I am not sure if this is a good sulution. Any comments to this? How it will be better?